# Lower bound for derivative of a non-constant function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Here is the problem. Let $g$ be a non-constant differentiable real function on $[a,b]$, and we know $g(a) = g(b) = 0$. I want to prove that there is a $c\in(a,b)$ such that
$$\lvert g'(c)\rvert > \frac{4}{(b-a)^2} \int_a^b\lvert g(t)\rvert dt$$
I kept trying to prove it via contradiction, which seems like the right idea. To be more specific, I tried using different combinations of the fundamental theorem of calculus and the mean value theorem, but I didn't get much anywhere. I think I'm missing a key insight, because I'm not sure how to use all the information to get the answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track, trying to use the mean value theorem to obtain a bound. I think the key "step" here is following the intuition that the maximum value for $g'(c)$ restricts the shape of $g(t)$, forcing its graph to lie in a triangular region. More formally:

Let $M = \sup_{a\le t\le b} |g'(t)|$. (If $M$ does not exist, then the conclusion is obvious.) By the mean value theorem, we have the following two bounds on $|g(t)|$:
$$ M(t-a)\ge |g(t)|\qquad\text{and}\qquad M(b-t)\ge |g(t)|. $$
Combining them, we obtain
\begin{align*}
\int_a^b |g(t)|\,dt &= \int_a^{(a+b)/2} |g(t)|\,dt + \int_{(a+b)/2}^b|g(t)|\,dt \\
&\le \int_a^{(a+b)/2} M(t-a)\,dt + \int_{(a+b)/2}^bM(b-t)\,dt \\
&= \frac{M(a-b)^2}{4}.
\end{align*}

Note that the inequality is strict unless $g$ is a triangle, in which case it is not differentiable. Thus the left-hand side and right-hand side differ by more than $\alpha > 0$, and we can choose $c$ so that $f'(c)$ is within $2\alpha/(a-b)^2$ of $M$.

Comment: You are assuming that $g'$ is continuous, but this is not included in the hypotheses

Comment: They only assumed continuity of $g'$ to establish $M$. They can jut say $M$ is the supremum of $g'$ in that range and it would still work (if there were no supremum then clearly the inequality holds).

Comment: @AhmedHussein For a minute I thought you were saying MVT required continuity of the derivative, which it doesn't. But no, that's presumably not your point. You're right, he has to change $\max$ to $\sup$. And then alas showing that $M\ge$ whatever doesn't _quite_ prove what's required.... hmm. There must be a simple fix. (Seems like the extremal case is $g'=M$ on the left half, $g'=-M$ on the right half. But that $g$ is not differentiable. That $g$ is no problem, and it seems to me that that's the only $g$ that could be a problem. Not that that's a proof...)

Comment: @Daishisan Just changing $\max$ to $\sup$ doesn't _quite_ fix it. Because then showing $M\ge A$ does not quite show that there exists $c$ with $|g'(c)|\ge A$.

Comment: The inequality is strict unless $g$ is a triangle and therefore not differentiable though (I suppose he should have noted this).

Comment: I double-checked the problem, and it only says $g$ is non-constant and differentiable, nothing about the continuity of $g'$.

Comment: I read the comments, and it sounds like the issues are resolved and the proof makes sense. Just need to change max to sup, and note that the inequality is strict unless $g$ looks like a triangle (which isn't differentiable). Is that correct?

Comment: Thanks guys for catching that! I've updated my answer so that it is complete.